# add prefix to a cell in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a cell in a (google)spreadsheet document (let's say L7) where I usually put a numeric value (like, say: "28", "12", "87"...).

I'm trying to make a formula that adds a letter in front (or sometime at the end) of these numbers (like this: "x01", "y02" or "03z"...)

So that whenever I type a number on this cell, a letter is put in front (or after) these two digits. And nothing to appear, if I don't put the number.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom format but the added letter or letters will be determined by being either a positive, negative or 0 number entered.
So if you wanted to add an A or B to the front of the entered number you would build the custom format "A"0;"B"0;0

So if you enter 5 the cell will show A5 and if you enter a negative 5 the cell will show B5 and no entry will show nothing.  Switching the position of the "A" and the 0 will change the entry to 5A.